# Integration of Shenzhen Concox Information Technology Tracker GT06

Tags: integration, tracker

I am using OpenGTS for some time for my organization. I was using TK103 family tracker but now my company changed tracker and brought GT06 made by Shenzhen Concox Information Technology Co. Ltd. This tracker protocol is entirely different and I am unable to create its server. Can anyone help me for this tracker integration or let me know which already integrated tracker is somehow similar to this one. Just give me a tip and I will manage rest. I am copying some protocol for your reference.

5.1.3. Examples
Examples of the login message packet sent by the terminal to the server and the response packet sent by the server to the terminal are as follows: (in the examples the terminal ID is 123456789012345.
Example of data packet sent by the terminal `78 780 0D 01 01 23 45 67 89 01 23 45 00 01 8C DD 0D 0A`

Example of response packet returned by the server

```
78 78 05 01 00 01 D9 DC 0D 0A

Shenzhen Concox Information Technology Co.,Ltd www.cothinking.net/
Copyright Reserved.
5.2. Location Data Packet (combined information package of GPS and LBS)
5.2.1. Terminal Sending Location Data Packet to Server
Format Length(Byte) Example
Start Bit 2 0x78 0x78
Packet Length 1 0x1F
Protocol Number 1 0x12
Date Time 6 0x0B 0x08 0x1D 0x11 0x2E 0x10
Quantity of
GPS
information
satellites
1 0xCF
Latitude 4 0x02 0x7A 0xC7 0xEB
Longitude 4 0x0C 0x46 0x58 0x49
Speed 1 0x00
GPS
Information
Course,
Status
2 0x14 0x8F
MCC 2 0x01 0xCC
MNC 1 0x00
LAC 2 0x28 0x7D
LBS
Information
Cell ID 3 0x00 0x1F 0xB8
Serial Number 2 0x00 0x03
Error Check 2 0x80 0x81
Information
Content
Stop Bit 2 0x0D 0x0A
```

Comment: Please anyone help us on this topic still stuck

Comment: if still stuck, just holler.  have both tk103 and gt06 solved.  c++

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Traccar](http://www.traccar.org/) server to track GT06 devices. It can be used as stand alone tracking system or if you prefer OpenGTS you can easily integrate two systems (use OpenGTS web interface and Traccar for device communication). Configuration file for integrating Traccar and OpenGTS can be found [here](http://www.traccar.org/docs/opengts.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

the GT06 protocol is different from the tk103.

the 4th byte (0x01) indicates a login protocol call for tracker with IMEI  01 23 45 67 89 01 23 45 (remove first zero).

it should be answered and the socket kept open.  you will receiva a 0x13 or 0x12 message (probably).

a 0x12 message has GPS location data.

i expect that you are not doing this blindfolded.  if needed, refer to [coding protocol manual](http://www.iconcox.com/uploads/soft/130627/1-13062F94158.pdf).  please note that some discrepancies may appear between concox and robustel units, even though both are variants of the original GreenTel GT06.

Comment: My "Heacent TK102B Magnet GSM" from DX is also using this GT06 protocol.

Comment: interesting!  i just acquired a TK102 and it runs on a completely different protocol!  stay away from TX5.

Comment: Need your help for implementing server to communicate with TK06A device.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal how do i contact you?

Comment: SkypeId: ajinkya.jeurkar Email: jeurkarajinkya@yahoo.com

Comment: I have an AWS server, how do I send data to my server from concox? It's not mentioned anywhere?

Comment: I have also posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191500/integration-of-shenzhen-concox-information-technology-tracker-gt06-with-ec2) on it. Could you please answer that?

Comment: @SarasArya you must configure your tracker with server info (IP and port), which can be done by sms or (depending on model) via usb with the appropriate sw (which not all trackers distributors make available)