# Integration of Shenzhen Concox Information Technology Tracker GT06 with EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, integration, tracker

I have a concox GT06 device from which I want to send tracking data to my AWS Server.

The [coding protocol manual](http://www.iconcox.com/uploads/soft/130627/1-13062F94158.pdf) that comes with it only explains the data structure and protocol.

How does my server receive the GPS data collected by my tracker?

Comment: the question is absolutely valid and whoever recommended closing shows complete ignorance of the tracking platform environment.  DONT TOUCH WHAT YOU CANT FIX, BOYS AND GIRLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Verify if your server allows you to open sockets, which most low cost solutions do NOT allow for security reasons (i recommend using an Amazon EC2 virtual machine as your platform).
2. Choose a port on which your application will listen to incoming data, verify if it is open (if not open it) and code your application (i use C++) to listen to that port.
3. Compile and run your application on the server (and make sure that it stays alive).
4. Configure your tracker (usually by sending an sms to it) to send data to your server's IP and to the port which your application is listening to.

If you are, as i suspect you are, just beginning, consider that you will invest 2 to 3 weeks to develop this solution from scratch.  You might also consider looking for a predeveloped tracking platform, which may or may not be acceptable in terms of data security.

You can find [examples and tutorials online](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/sockets_server_client.php).  I am usually very open with my coding and would gladly send a copy of the socket server, but, in this case, for security reasons, i cannot do so.

Comment: i know that you already use amazon EC2, nevertheless i explicitly explain why i i recommend that others follow your choice in cloud computing.

Comment: Hi tony, thank you for the response. I am thankful not only for the answer but also on the point that for a newbie on certain topics people start voting to close their questions instead of answering/guiding to the right resource. I really appreciate you taking a stand against such SO bullies.

Comment: Also, I got the answer. I was checking at the wrong place. To anyone facing a similar issue check out the user manual and not the protocol manual of the device. It mostly has the info on how to setup the web platform.

Comment: i cant stand these badge hunters who will jump at first opportunity of voting to close posts just to get an extra gold star.  Your post deserves to stay up and be discussed.  I hope people come up with better and better solutions.  i'm here to learn, not to accumulate fictitious bonus points.

Comment: @tony gil ... I am developing gps tracking solution. I can successfully connected to concox gt06 device. My problem is with scaling and thread management. Can I use UDP protocol for GT06?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct parsing of TCP or UDP packets you may use simplified solution putting in-between middleware backends specialized in data parsing e.g. [flespi](https://flespi.com/quick-start).
In such approach you may use HTTP REST API to fetch each new portion of data from trackers sent to you dedicated IP:port (called channel) or even send standardized commands with HTTP REST to connected devices.
At the same time it is possible to open MQTT connection using standard libraries and receive converted into JSON messages from devices [as MQTT in real time](https://flespi.com/mqtt-api), which is even better then REST due to almost zero latency.
If you are using python you may take a look at open-source [flespi_receiver](https://github.com/flespi-software/flespi_receiver/) library. In this approach with 10 lines of code you may have on your EC2 whole parsed into JSON messages from Concox GT06.